# remove blank spaces and numbers

Tags: shell-script

I want to remove only these

```
0.10
0.10
0.10
0.10
1.4
1.4
1.4
2.7
```

But don't remove these lines and numbers

```
activemq 5.6.0+dfsg1-4+deb8u2
akonadi-backend-mysql 1.13.0-2+deb8u2
akonadi-backend-postgresql 1.13.0-2+deb8u2
akonadi-backend-sqlite 1.13.0-2+deb8u2
akonadi-server 1.13.0-2+deb8u2
apache2 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2.2-bin 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2.2-common 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-bin 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-data 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-dev 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-doc 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-mpm-event 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-mpm-itk 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
apache2-mpm-prefork 2.4.10-10+de
```

Comment: please format your post, it's hard to read it  in current form

Comment: If you just want to remove any line starting by any number you can try `grep -v "^[0-9]" filename`

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio quote the search string, else it is open to shell interpretation and file names like `^2` in that directory will spoil the command.. it is a good practice to follow

Comment: thank you so much Sundeep  and ZumodeVidrio that helped me :)

Comment: @daisy thanks for editing my question im new to this forum, bare with me :)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Could you show a sample of your input file and your desired output from the same sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove any line starting by any number you can try:

```
grep -v "^[0-9]" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -e '^$' -e '^[.]$' -e '[.].*[.]' -e '[^0-9.]' yourfile
```

Here we are progressively filtering the nature of the lines that we want to keep:

```
a) thoroughly empty lines,
b) lines that are exactly a dot,
c) lines that comprise at least 2 dots,
d) finally, lines that have at least 1 nondigit &/or 1 dot. (Note: a solitary dot
   has already been filtered out by step-b) earlier.)
```